# Rescaling the null coordinates

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, conventions

Given a $4$-dimensional spacetime described by four coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$, we usually define the null coordinates by,

\begin{equation}
u = \frac{t-r}{2}, \quad v = \frac{t+r}{2}
\end{equation}

which can be solved for $(t,r)$ so that,

\begin{equation}
t = v+u, \quad r = v-u
\end{equation}

where we can view this as shown in the diagram,

[image]

My question is, is it possible to define the null coordinates,

\begin{equation}
u = 2(t-r), \quad v = 2(t+r)
\end{equation}

so that we have,

\begin{equation}
t = \frac{v+u}{4}, \quad r = \frac{v-u}{4}
\end{equation}

Of course, in this case, we are rescaling the basis $u$ and $v$ pointing in the null directions OR we are rescaling $t$ and $r$. I just want to know whether there is nothing wrong with this physically.